# Docker with consul limited netork communication

Tags: docker, consul

I am using a Consul and Docker. My service is starting up, picking up a free port and registering in consul. So OK it works.

But occasionally, consul (consul:latest) needs to ping my service (which is not running in a container, but instead is a hosted app on a server) to check if its running (check service health state). This does not work.

The service is registering but pinging it does not work. The way the health check works is that consul sends an http request to the service on its registered address (for example http://localhost:40000/Health) which responds with 200 if it is alive.

my docker-compose.yml looks like:

```
consul:
  image: consul:latest
  command: consul agent -dev -log-level=warn -ui -client=0.0.0.0
  hostname: consul
  container_name: consul
  ports:
    - 8500:8500
```

Another thing when I change Health check from http to tcp I am getting

> "dial tcp 127.0.0.1:40000: connect: connection refused"

I tried using stand-alone consul executable on a local machine and it works fine. So my question is is there a way to unblock free communication between docker and locally hosted service?

Comment: Can you provide the json that you use to register the service (and the health-check) with consul?

Comment: Just to be clear: You docker Consul container is running on a machine on which your service is also running and listening on `localhost:4000`? And you want to perform health check from the container to this service?

Comment: Aye, thats the case. And also I do not have consul registration json, reason is that I bind service on first free tcp port and then using ConsulAPI register it dynamically.